# Django Rest Framework use of `permissions.IsAuthenticated` rises an erro

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `ModelViewSet` and I want it to be accessed only by authenticated users, so I added the `permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated)`, but I get an error:

```
TypeError at /es/general/countries/
'type' object is not iterable
```

This is the `ViewSet`:

```
class CountryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated)
    queryset = models.Country.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CountrySerializer
```

If I remove the `IsAuthenticated` assignment line, the ViewSet works, but with it, I get the error.

I'll appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one little comma:

```
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
# This works
for a in permission_classes:
    print("fine")

permission_classes_error = (IsAuthenticated)
#TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
for b in permission_classes_error:
    print("fine")
```

With the comma, we are creating a new tuple (which is an iterable type) with just one element. Without it we are assigning `IsAuthenticated` (which is of type `object` and therefore not iterable) to `permission_classes`.

Your fixed `ViewSet` looks like this:

```
class CountryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = models.Country.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CountrySerializer
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly now (I thought the parenthesis where enough to make it a tuple)